# Correct notation for cross-level interaction

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, notation

I am wondering if I am using the correct notation for a multilevel model with a cross-level interaction (i.e., a multilevel model with an interaction between level 1 and 2 covariates).

Let $Y_{tj}$ be a test score of the $jth$ student at time $t$. For simplicity, let $gender$ be the only level two (i.e., student level) covariate, and let $months$ be the only level 1 (i.e., repeated observation level) covariate.

Typically in the context of cross-level interactions, which in this example is an interaction between $gender$ and $months$, the interaction is a random effect and can be denoted using the notation below.

(Level-1 model)

$Y_{tj} = \beta_{0j} + \beta_{1j}months + r_{tj}$, where $r_{tj} \tilde{} N(0,\sigma^2)$

(Level-2 model)

$\beta_{0j} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01}gender + u_{0j}$, where $u_{0j} \tilde{} N(0,\tau_{00})$

$\beta_{1j} = \gamma_{10} + \gamma_{11}gender + u_{1j}$,  where $u_{1j} \tilde{} N(0,\tau_{10})$

I am not interested in estimating $\tau_{10}$. Or, put differently, I want the coefficient corresponding to $months$ to be fixed. Given this, is the below notation correct?

$Y_{tj} = \beta_{0j} + \beta_{1}months + r_{tj}$, where $r_{tj} \tilde{} N(0,\sigma^2)$

(Level-2 model)

$\beta_{0j} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01}gender + u_{0j}$, where $u_{0j} \tilde{} N(0,\tau_{00})$

$\beta_{1} = \gamma_{10} + \gamma_{11}gender$

Any comments on my notation are welcome! Though I would also appreciate references to articles estimating such cross-level interactions.

Comment: Interaction terms would have to contain both "month" and "gender", e.g. "gender:month". But you don't seem to include them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Frank notes in a comment, what you show in your question does not evaluate  an interaction between `months` and `gender`. If we follow the [Wikipedia naming of levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_model), Level 1 represents the observations at the individual level.* All "fixed-effect" predictors would be included at that level. Your Level-1 model thus should include both of those predictors individually, plus an interaction term between them if that's what you want.

Level 2 then allows for the intercepts and regression coefficients at Level 1 to differ depending on which group or individual is being observed. If you don't want to allow the coefficient(s) for `months` to differ among individuals, don't include a corresponding random effect.

---

*When you call the student-level observations "Level 2" you seem to be defining the levels differently from how Wikipedia does. In Wikipedia, Level 1 represents the individual-level observations. I find the *numbering* of levels to be more confusing than helpful. For me, the form of a linear mixed model represented by Equation 2 in the R [`lme4` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf) better captures the joint combination of fixed and random effects in a mixed model.

Comment: Thanks, the lme4 vignette really helped clarify things. Though, according to the article below, my interpretation of what a cross-level covariates is correct.                                                                                   Peugh, J. L. (2010). A practical guide to multilevel modeling. Journal of school psychology, 48(1), 85-112.

Comment: @Student100 I keep getting confused by the level numbering, cross-level terminology, and all that. So I try to avoid such things. If you use lme4 and are careful with how you name the random factors, all takes care of itself. You just specify the fixed-effect predictors and choose the random-effects structure you want. Having the level hierarchy well defined does help with setting up Bayesian mixed models.